# PowerBI calculated column - translate question

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to create a calculated column that can translate several values into something that is more readable.

My example is something like a list of company departments, most are formatted with a formal name in the example below I'd like to calculate a column to convert acctng to Accounting

- Sales
- Marketing
- Manufacturing
- Support
- acctng

So the calculated column would read

- Sales
- Marketing
- Manufacturing
- Support
- Accounting

I'd like to create a calculated column that transfers over all items as they are except, when we see accting it's converted to Accounting.  I know that I can do a transformation in the data view, however, I'm hoping for a dax formula.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that with DAX, then you can [create a new column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns) and use [SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax) function:

```
Department (Translated) = 
    SWITCH(Sales[Department]; 
    "acctng"; "Accounting"; 
    "smtng"; "Something else"; 
    Sales[Department])
```

[image]